# Listen to keystrokes in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to implement a 2-step keystroke mechanism in AppleScript.

I'd like to me able to type command-Y (for example) and then listen to the NEXT keystroke, and execute commands depending on what the keystroke is.

This would allow me to create a service that listens to the command-Y, and then executes something.

Is that possible at all, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible via Applescript. You can record in Script Editor, but you cannot check for certain key strokes and record that. I think it's a matter of security, since hackers could use it to steal user names and passwords.

Not sure what type of commands you want to do, but I'd go for a `display dialog list` and let the user pick the command they want.